# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit doesn't perform Console.WriteLine

Tags: c#, appdomain

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace empty
{
    class Program
    {
        static Program()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += ExitHandler;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
        static void ExitHandler(object o, EventArgs args)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(fs, new double[30000000]);         
            }
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Create))
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(fs, new double[30000000]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("end");
        }
    }
}
```

I expecting to get output: 
"end"
but get nothing. What am I doing wrong?

I intentionally use 2 serializations because such behaviour doesn't happen with 1 serialization.

Comment: Is your file being created as expected?

Comment: @Steve Guidi, during deserialization I get SerializationException: "End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed", but I haven't exceptions during serialization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for `ProcessExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.processexit), you'll find this:

> The total execution time of all ProcessExit event handlers is limited, just as the total execution time of all finalizers is limited at process shutdown. The default is two seconds.

So, if whatever action you're doing in that handler takes more than two seconds, it's not going to execute completely. This seems to be exactly the problem you're having.